# Trying to compile Nite2 sample in OpenNI

Tags: kinect, openni

I am new in Kinect SDK, therefore I am asking for your help solving this problem:

> 1>------ Build started: Project: UserViewer, Configuration: Debug
>   Win32 ------
>
> 1>Viewer.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
>   _*imp*_oniInitialize referenced in function "public: static enum openni::Status __cdecl openni::OpenNI::initialize(void)"
>   (?initialize@OpenNI@openni@@SA?AW4Status@2@XZ)
>
> 1>Viewer.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
>   _*imp*_oniShutdown referenced in function "public: static void __cdecl openni::OpenNI::shutdown(void)" (?shutdown@OpenNI@openni@@SAXXZ)
>
> 1>Viewer.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
>   _*imp*_oniGetExtendedError referenced in function "public: static char const * __cdecl openni::OpenNI::getExtendedError(void)"
>   (?getExtendedError@OpenNI@openni@@SAPBDXZ)
>
> 1>Viewer.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
>   _*imp*_oniDeviceOpen referenced in function "public: enum openni::Status __thiscall openni::Device::open(char const *)"
>   (?open@Device@openni@@QAE?AW4Status@2@PBD@Z)
>
> 1>Viewer.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
>   _*imp*_oniDeviceClose referenced in function "public: void __thiscall openni::Device::close(void)" (?close@Device@openni@@QAEXXZ)
>
> 1>Viewer.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
>   _*imp*_oniDeviceGetInfo referenced in function "private: enum openni::Status __thiscall openni::Device::_setHandle(struct _OniDevice
>   *)" (?_setHandle@Device@openni@@AAE?AW4Status@2@PAU_OniDevice@@@Z)
>
> 1>Viewer.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
>   _*imp*_oniDeviceIsPropertySupported referenced in function "public: bool __thiscall openni::Device::isPropertySupported(int)const "
>   (?isPropertySupported@Device@openni@@QBE_NH@Z)
>
> 1>Viewer.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
>   _*imp*_oniDeviceIsCommandSupported referenced in function "public: bool __thiscall openni::Device::isCommandSupported(int)const "
>   (?isCommandSupported@Device@openni@@QBE_NH@Z)
>
> 1>Viewer.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
>   _*imp*_oniFrameAddRef referenced in function "public: void __thiscall openni::VideoFrameRef::_setFrame(struct OniFrame *)"
>   (?_setFrame@VideoFrameRef@openni@@QAEXPAUOniFrame@@@Z)
>
> 1>Viewer.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
>   _*imp*_oniFrameRelease referenced in function "public: void __thiscall openni::VideoFrameRef::release(void)"
>   (?release@VideoFrameRef@openni@@QAEXXZ)
>
> 1>Viewer.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
>   _*imp*_niteInitialize referenced in function "public: static enum nite::Status __cdecl nite::NiTE::initialize(void)"
>   (?initialize@NiTE@nite@@SA?AW4Status@2@XZ)
>
> 1>Viewer.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
>   _*imp*_niteShutdown referenced in function "public: static void __cdecl nite::NiTE::shutdown(void)" (?shutdown@NiTE@nite@@SAXXZ)
>
> 1>Viewer.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
>   _*imp*_niteInitializeUserTracker referenced in function "public: enum nite::Status __thiscall nite::UserTracker::create(class openni::Device
>   *)" (?create@UserTracker@nite@@QAE?AW4Status@2@PAVDevice@openni@@@Z)
>
> 1>Viewer.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
>   _*imp*_niteInitializeUserTrackerByDevice referenced in function "public: enum nite::Status __thiscall nite::UserTracker::create(class
>   openni::Device *)"
>   (?create@UserTracker@nite@@QAE?AW4Status@2@PAVDevice@openni@@@Z)
>
> 1>Viewer.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
>   _*imp*_niteShutdownUserTracker referenced in function "public: void __thiscall nite::UserTracker::destroy(void)" (?destroy@UserTracker@nite@@QAEXXZ)
>
> 1>Viewer.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
>   _*imp*_niteStartSkeletonTracking referenced in function "public: enum nite::Status __thiscall
>   nite::UserTracker::startSkeletonTracking(short)"
>   (?startSkeletonTracking@UserTracker@nite@@QAE?AW4Status@2@F@Z)
>
> 1>Viewer.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
>   _*imp*_niteStartPoseDetection referenced in function "public: enum nite::Status __thiscall
>   nite::UserTracker::startPoseDetection(short,enum nite::PoseType)"
>   (?startPoseDetection@UserTracker@nite@@QAE?AW4Status@2@FW4PoseType@2@@Z)
>
> 1>Viewer.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
>   _*imp*_niteReadUserTrackerFrame referenced in function "public: enum nite::Status __thiscall nite::UserTracker::readFrame(class
>   nite::UserTrackerFrameRef *)"
>   (?readFrame@UserTracker@nite@@QAE?AW4Status@2@PAVUserTrackerFrameRef@2@@Z)
>
> 1>Viewer.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
>   _*imp*_niteUserTrackerFrameRelease referenced in function "public: void __thiscall nite::UserTrackerFrameRef::release(void)"
>   (?release@UserTrackerFrameRef@nite@@QAEXXZ)
>
> 1>Viewer.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
>   _*imp*_niteConvertJointCoordinatesToDepth referenced in function "public: enum nite::Status __thiscall
>   nite::UserTracker::convertJointCoordinatesToDepth(float,float,float,float
>   *,float *)const " (?convertJointCoordinatesToDepth@UserTracker@nite@@QBE?AW4Status@2@MMMPAM0@Z)
>
> 1>C:\Program
>   Files\PrimeSense\NiTE2\Samples\UserViewer..\Bin\UserViewer.exe :
>   fatal error  LNK1120: 20 unresolved externals
>
> ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

I am working with OpenNI2 and Nite2 and trying to compile one of the Nite2 Sample projects.

Answer (score -2):

OpenNI2 doesn't support Kinect, as long as I know, maybe you can try with old OpenNI, at least that's what I learned, after trying the same, but I don't know under windows, I'm using GNU/ubuntu.

Comment: If you have Kinect SDK installed, OpenNI 2.0 will work with Kinect Device.

I tried it yesterday with NIViewer and I manage to run it with Kinect for Xbox Device.